# How to config Redis cache expiration with RedisSessionStateProvider?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redis, session-state, nosql

I create a MVC sample app uses [RedisSessionStateProvider](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/05/12/announcing-asp-net-session-state-provider-for-redis-preview-release.aspx) as a custom session state. I set a variable into session state and it works great. But I do not know how to synchronize expiration of items in the session and Redis. Could anyone please help?

This is parameters from web.config

```
        <!--
      <add name="MySessionStateStore" 
        host = "127.0.0.1" [String]
        port = "" [number]
        accessKey = "" [String]
        ssl = "false" [true|false]
        throwOnError = "true" [true|false]
        retryTimeoutInMilliseconds = "5000" [number]
        databaseId = "0" [number]
        applicationName = "MvcTestApp" [String]
        connectionTimeoutInMilliseconds = "5000" [number]
        operationTimeoutInMilliseconds = "1000" [number]
        connectionString = "<Valid StackExchange.Redis connection string>" [String]
        loggingClassName = "<Assembly qualified class name that contains logging method specified below>" [String]
        loggingMethodName = "<Logging method should be defined in loggingClass. It should be public, static, does not take any parameters and should have a return type of System.IO.TextWriter.>" [String]
      />
    -->
```

I am using lateset versions:
RedisSessionStateProvider version 1.6.4
Redis version 2.8.21

Comment: Are you talking about expiring your custom keys from Redis at the same time as your session? Or you are afraid that your session items from Redis might not expire when the session expires?

Comment: @LiviuCostea thanks for your questions :) I don't know if the items from Redis will be expired or not at the same time with items in Session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All session state providers have no attribute about expiration. There is a [HttpSessionState.Timeout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.timeout(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Gets and sets the amount of time, in minutes, allowed between requests before the session-state provider terminates the session.
>
> The Timeout property cannot be set to a value greater than 525,600 minutes (1 year). The default value is 20 minutes.

So, asp.net manages for us this logic, we don't need to worry about it.

On redis client, you can use two commands `keys *` to see all keys, `ttl <key>` to see when it will be expired.

Comment: Ah, thank you for the timeout property, I forgot it ;)

Answer (score 3):

The expiration of the session items set in Redis will expire when Session will expire, you don't need to do anything about it. It will be handled by the RedisSessionStateProvider

Comment: I make my app sleeps few minutes but do not know when items in Redis will be remove. Can we check this value ?

Comment: Configure you web app to use Redis session provider, start it and then you can use some Redis commands to see what keys http://redis.io/commands/keys will be created  and what is their time to live - http://redis.io/commands/ttl And you can also check what happened with the redis keys after your session has expired